# Advertising in an UWP app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I recently started developing UWP apps for Windows 10. Right now I only have one app published in the store, it's free and has no advertising. I'm developing another app, and I would love to make money from this app through advertising (the app will also be free)
What types of advertising do you recommend?
Where can I get more information about advertising in uwp apps?
What care should I take? And what recommendations do you give me?

Comment: This question should be closed for multiple reasons: *"primarily opinion-based"*, *"asking for off-site resources"*, *"too broad"*, and a mixture of *"too broad"* and *"primarily opinion-based"*. Please take the [tour], visit the [help], and read [ask] in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has guidance on displaying Ads in your apps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/display-ads-in-your-app

There's also an advertising SDK that links with the Dev Center (which makes integrating ads easy) and there's more on this at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125365.aspx

Unfortunately your more specific questions are best answered with "it depends".
The most appropriate types of advertising will depend on your app, it's usage, and the user base. It may not even be appropriate to try and monetize your app with advertising. Sorry, I know that's not what you want to hear but it's a very open question not really suited to this site. Instead I recommend starting by looking at the above links.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Matt said, there are something that you may need to note.
 One is the Advertising SDK, for UWP app, you should install [Microsoft Store Service SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdMediator.MicrosoftStoreServicesSDK).

Another is the [test value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/test-mode-values), when you are developing your UWP app, you can use test value(application ID and ad unit ID) to check if the ads show, and then if you want to publish it, you need to update your code to use an application ID and ad unit ID provide by the Windows Dev Center dashboard, so your app can receive ads in your published app.

Finally you may need to pay attention to the [supported banner ad sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads).

If you have some problems about ads in your app, please refer to [troubleshooting guide.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/xaml-and-c-troubleshooting-guide)